# ListView, OnItemClick not being called?

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment, onitemclicklistener

I have a `FragmentActivity` that controls a `ListFragment`; that `ListFragment` contains a generic `ListView`, `Adapter`, and draws an `ArrayList` from a `Singleton` that I have created.

When in the `onCreateView` method of my `ListFragment` I put the following code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater viewInflation, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle SavedInstantState) {
    cycleviewfragment = viewInflation.inflate(
            R.layout.cycleviewfragment_page, container, false);
    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    Singleton mySingleton = Singleton.getInstance();
    basicList = (ListView) cycleviewfragment.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<listControlObject>(getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mySingleton.getA1());

    this.setListAdapter(adapter);

    addButton = (Button) cycleviewfragment.findViewById(R.id.addbutton);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    listaddactivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });

    basicList.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    Log.d("basicListtester", "Testing onClickItem call");
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            listdetailactivity.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("selectedObjectIndex",arg2);
                    getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);

                }

            });

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return cycleviewfragment;
}
```

Any ideas as to why when I add items to my list they do not react and the OnItemClick is not called?

Thanks guys.

**[Update]**

I tried implementing it with `basicList.setAdapter(adapter);` which still did not work.

also tried having my `ListFragment` implement `OnItemClickListener` and added the method to the class; which did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `ListFragment` you shouldn't set `onItemClickListener` to your list. There is already a method in `ListFragment` that you should override.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    //Do your thingy.
}
```

Comment: When overriding that; how do I make sure my ListView basicList listens for; basicList.setOnItemClickListener(this) returns error.

Comment: Also; I'm reading up on other posts that say if you have other interactable views inside of your ListFragment (my button, for example) that it can mess things up?

Comment: You should not call basicList.setOnItemClickListener(this)  at all. You will not set a listener. It will called automatically.

Comment: Ah my apologies; it works now. Thank you for your assistance! I did not know it would just call automatically...

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
basicList.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

instead of

```
this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Use same instance of ListView for setting `Adapter` and `setOnItemClickListener`.

Comment: Still not working; I tried switching things around and having my ListFragment implement OnItemClickListener and setting it up that way; however that does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

you should override `onListItemClick`, since your class extends `ListFragment`. From the doc:

> This method will be called when an item in the list is selected.
>   Subclasses should override.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) the documentation

Comment: Is there a difference between onListItemClick and onItemClick?

Comment: the documentations says that subclass of ListActivity should override it.

Comment: Neither of the answers had worked; I tried having my FragmentList implement OnItemClickListener which also did not do the trick.